# ActionMailer: undefined method `recipients' for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, actionmailer

I am writing a test, on Rails 3.2, for one of my ActionMailers - InvitationMailer, however, it doesnt seem to find the "recipients" method.

My test looks like the following:

```
  describe "Invitation" do
    it "should send invitation email to user" do
    user = Factory :user

    email = InvitationMailer.invitation_email(user).deliver
    # Send the email, then test that it got queued
    assert !ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.empty?

    # Test the body of the sent email contains what we expect it to
    assert_equal [user.email], email.to
    assert_equal "You have been Invited!", email.subject

    end
```

My InvitationMailer looks like this:

```
class InvitationMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "webmaster@myapp.com"

  def invitation_email(user)
    recipients  user.email
    from        "invitations@myapp.com"
    subject     "You have been Invited!"
    body        :user => user
  end

end
```

I however, get the following error msg:

```
 Failure/Error: email = InvitationEmail.invitation_email(user).deliver
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `recipients' for #<InvitationMailer:0x007fca0b41f7f8>
```

Any idea what it could be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an example from the [Rails Guide for ActionMailer](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html):

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default :from => "notifications@example.com"

  def welcome_email(user)
    @user = user
    @url  = "http://example.com/login"
    mail(:to => user.email,
         :subject => "Welcome to My Awesome Site",
         :template_path => 'notifications',
         :template_name => 'another')
  end
end
```

Making your code look more like this may make it easier to resolve, so I'd first rewrite it to look like:

```
class InvitationMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "webmaster@myapp.com"

  def hassle_email(user)
    @user = user
    mail(:to => user.email,
         :subject => "You have been Invited!")
  end
end
```

Then you'll have the `:to`, the `:subject` and the `@user` object passed to the mailer 'view' which is like any other view.

Snce you're using `recipients` I wasn't sure if you were trying to send the email to multiple email addresses. If so, according to the ActionMailer documentation:

> It is possible to send email to one or more recipients in one email
>   (for e.g. informing all admins of a new signup) by setting the list of
>   emails to the :to key. The list of emails can be an array of email
>   addresses or a single string with the addresses separated by commas.

Comment: The syntax seems a bit different. Apparently recipients, from, etc. are method calls - which from your answer, have not been used. Instead you are using a mail method call. What is the difference? (reference http://railscasts.com/episodes/61-sending-email)

Comment: @Newton While the railscasts are normally fantastic resources, you need to be careful about using them if they're too old. The one you're referencing is from 5 years ago almost. In general, always check the latest rails docs if you have a question.